# Show that such numbers exists

Tags: trigonometry

Show that there exists number $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2} )$ such that:
$$ \tan x= \sqrt x $$
How to approach this, because i have utterly no idea.

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph of the two functions?

Comment: but i do not want to prove this graphically

Comment: yeah, but drawing things would give you the idea.

Comment: @kurkowski, how *do* you want to prove it?  It's difficult to give a good answer without knowing what techniques (e.g., calculus) you have at your disposal.

Comment: obviously you can use calculus

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You're searching a point where $\tan x - \sqrt{x} = 0$. You could use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=\tan x-\sqrt x$. Then $f$ is continuous on $(0,{\pi\over 2})$. It can be seen that 
$f({\pi\over 6})\lt 0$ while $f({\pi\over 4})\gt 0$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: OK, thanks understand the method but could you explain why is it so that mean value theorem gives a result here ?

Comment: f is continuous and f(a)>0 and f(b)<0. since f is continuous, it intersects the x-axis in a point in (a,b). i.e., there is some c in (a,b) such that f(c)=0 or $\tan c =\sqrt c$